# Managing IIS .Net 4, .Net 2, x32, x64 root web.config & machine.config

Tags: configuration, iis-8.5

I am managing an IIS 8.5 farm and we have a mix of 32bit, 64bit, .Net 2 and .Net 4 applications in the farm.

We want to set things like the MachineKey, SessionState server and Retail mode, however we have to update it in 4 different places on each machine, so in a two node farm that's 8 xml files we have to update manually.

Is there a way with PowerShell, AppCmd etc to update these settings in all 4 places by specifying which one you want to update?

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\CONFIG
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\CONFIG
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\CONFIG
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\CONFIG
```

Or is there a 3rd party product that can manage this?

Comment: Probably only a third party product can achieve that.